# How is this plane also perpendicular to all multiples $cx$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra***

If the columns combine into $Ax=0$ then each row has $r\cdot x=0$

$$\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1 } & { a }_{ 2 } & { a }_{ 3 } \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} { x }_{ 1 } \\ { x }_{ 2 } \\ x_{ 3 } \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

By rows: $$\begin{bmatrix} { r_{ 1 }\cdot x } \\ r_{ 2 }\cdot x \\ r_{ 3 }\cdot x \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The three rows also lie in a plane. Why is that plane perpendicular to $x$?

**My answer:**

**Since $r_{ 1 }\cdot x=0\quad and\quad r_{ 2 }\cdot x=0\quad and\quad r_{ 3 }\cdot x=0$, all three rows are perpendicular to $x$. This must mean that the whole plane of rows is perpendicular to $x$.**

My answer seems to be just about in line with the answer given by Gilbert Strang; however, there was one part to his answer that I can't seem to conceptually understand. It saids *"the plane is also perpendicular to all multiples of $cx$"*. How is this true as well? I don't seem to understand that one part and I don't think it's something that I should just sweep under the rug and move on to the next problem.

Comment: $r_1\cdot (cx) = c(r_1\cdot x) = c(0) = 0$.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed something so simple. 

Also, how did you add those brackets around the vectors? It never displays properly when I add them.

Feel free to post that answer below. I will +1 and accept it.

Comment: Protip: if you want to know how someone rendered a bit of MathJax, right-click on it, hit "Show Math As > TeX Commands".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$r_1\cdot (cx) = c(r_1\cdot x) = c(0) = 0$$

Or in terms of matrices:

$$r_1\cdot (cx) = \mathbf {r_1}^T(c\mathbf x) = c(\mathbf {r_1}^T\mathbf x) = c(r_1\cdot x) = c(0) = 0$$

So essentially this is saying that if a plane (or other object) is orthogonal to a vector, then that plane (or other object) is orthogonal to *any* multiple of that vector (because of course, multiples of a vector are parallel to it).

Comment: multiples of a vector are parallel to what?

Comment: If $x\in V$, where $V$ is some real vector space (like $\Bbb R^3$ for instance), then $kx$ is parallel to $x$ for all $k\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: isn't $c\overrightarrow { v } $ just going to be bigger or smaller version of that same vector?

Comment: Yes.  Thinking about the vector $\vec v$ as an arrow in space, your statement means that $c\vec v$ points in the same (or opposite) direction as $\vec v$, right?  But that's just what the word "parallel" means.

Comment: I'm only getting more confused now, because of your last statement in parentheses. So, I will tell you what I understand and then you can correct me where my intuition is off.

So, if a plane is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow { v } $, then that plane is perpendicular to any $c\overrightarrow { v } $. Wouldn't multiples of that vector, $c\overrightarrow { v } $, be perpendicular to that plane? I don't understand how they could be parallel to it.

Comment: $c\vec v$ is a called a multiple of the vector $\vec v$. The directions of $c\vec v$ and $\vec v$ are the [same](http://www.math10.com/en/geometry/vectors-operations/imgFig8.gif) ([or opposite](http://media1.shmoop.com/images/calculus/calc_fn_vect_narr_graphik_43.png)), meaning that if we drew both of them as arrows with their tails at the origin a single line would pass through both. Thus $c\vec v$ is *parallel to* $\vec v$: NOT the plane. If $\vec v$ is perpendicular to some plane $B$ then $c\vec v$ will also be perpendicular to $B$, because $\vec v$ and $c\vec v$ are parallel to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30069/discussion-between-cherry-developer-and-bye-world).